# how to use firebasedatabase transactions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use firebase database transaction in my react native app. I want to update the users count whenever the user is added in database

here is the code I'm using

```
let dbCountPath = "/DatabaseUsersCount/" + "count"

    dbCountPath.transaction(function (current_value) {
      return (current_value || 0) + 1;
    });
```

I'm getting error of transaction is not exists ? how can we solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call `transaction` on a string. But the `transaction` method is only defined on a `Reference`, so you'll first have to get the reference for your path. Something like:

```
let dbCountPath = "/DatabaseUsersCount/" + "count"

firebase.database().ref(dbCountPath).transaction(function (current_value) {
  return (current_value || 0) + 1;
});
```